# Java Code Organization: Where to keep instance of static class

Tags: java, organization, code-organization

This question may be a little bit subjective, but I'm just trying to follow the best programming practices for organization of code.

I have a class `Polynomial` that makes a lot of reference to the class `Rational`, and in many different methods it uses a `Rational` value that is equivalent to 1, 0, or -1 for comparisons.

As such, I have the following constants defined:

```
public static final Rational ZERO    = new Rational(0);
public static final Rational ONE     = new Rational(1);
public static final Rational NEG_ONE = new Rational(-1);
```

However, the thing I'm not certain about is where to store these values in a meaningful way.

On the one hand, `Polynomial` is what uses them, so storing them inside of the class localizes it to where it is going to be used. This also means that it can be changed to private so that it is only used within the one class.

On the other hand, if it is defined inside of `Rational`, then all calls to the values become `Rational.ZERO`, `Rational.ONE`,`Rational.NEG_ONE` -- which makes it very human-readable, and organizes it in a lexically understandable manner. It also gives the opportunity to define similar constants in `Polynomial` as well if ever it were needed.

So basically, opinions aside, what's the most common practice for organization in something like this? Are my thoughts right for either of the locations for it, or is there another solution that I hadn't considered?

Comment: As far as I see, placing these constants in the `Rational` class is the most common way to do this (see e. g. the JDK `Boolean` or `Color` classes).

Comment: That's what I would have thought as well, because it becomes more obvious as to what the constants represent (after all, Polynomial.ONE would imply a Polynomial with a value representing '1'). I just started doubting it after I was told that it'd make more sense to localize it to the class using it.

Comment: Furthermore when `Rational` constants are going to be needed in other classes than `Polynomial` than you definitely see where they really should be placed into.
They should only be placed in `Polynomial` when they are constants only useful in context of this class. When these constants are very common for ´Rational´ then they should be placed there.

Comment: @Bitwize You should localize the constants if their value is specific to the `Polynomial` class, e. g. default values or limits or ...  In this case, the constants are not limited to a specific use case or application, so you should put them in the `Rational` class.

Comment: @RobinKrahl up, totally agree.

Comment: @RobinKrahl @FabianBarney Thanks guys! I just wanted to be sure about this. It made sense to me, it was just weird that someone told me otherwise for it. I mean, I'd understand for an arbitrary `Rational` value, but for ones that are more-or-less significant such as 1, 0, and -1 I figured it'd make sense to instantiate them in the same class that they represent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They should be in the `Rational` class since they are abstraction for rational numbers. It would be debatable if you would want to move them to a `RationalPolynomial` class, but even then I believe keeping them in `Rational` would be better.

A big requirement for doing this is making your **`Rational` class immutable**; otherwise you shouldn't expose them as public. Effective Java mentions at page 76:

> > Immutable classes should take advantage of this by encouraging clients to reuse existing instances wherever possible. One easy way to do this is to provide public static final constants for frequently used values. For example, the Complex class might provide these constants:

```
public static final Complex ZERO = new Complex(0, 0);
public static final Complex ONE = new Complex(1, 0);
public static final Complex I = new Complex(0, 1);
```

Comment: +1 for adding the point about immutability. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion - you could do something similar like Java does with Strings, which is, reusing existing instances.

So you could give Rational private constructors, which prevents other classes to create direct instances of it, and introduce a public static factory method, e.g. "Rational.get(1)" or "Rational.of(1)".

That way, you could keep some popular numbers like the ones you mentioned in static fields and return them instead of creating new instances. You could even think of keeping a (limited) pool that could increase performance further in case a bigger number of Rationals are reused over and over again.

The big plus of this solution is that new developers, that don't know about the constants you introduced, do not use "Rational(1)" by mistake, as everyone is forced to use the factory method.

Of course, with that approach, you should also make sure the Rational class is immutable!